# Obtener Valores De Select Option Desde Una Base De Datos php con postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

Me podrian aydar un poco con este codigo estoy tratando de hacer un select con lo datos almacenados en la tabla tbl_estatus, cuando lo corro no muestra nungun valor

```
     <form  method="POST">
     <td><center>Estatus:
     <select name="id_estatus">
    <?php
     $conex = "host=localhost port=5433 dbname=prueba user=postgre password=josec123";
    $query = pg_query($conex, 'SELECT id_estatus, desc_estatus FROM tbl_estatus');
 while ($datos= pg_fetch_array($query)) {
   ?>
<option value="<?php echo $datos['id_estatus']?>"><?php echo 
$datos['desc_estatus']?></option>
<?php
 }
 ?>
  </select></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para hacer la consulta debes conectarte, para lo cual reemplaza esta linea.

```
$conex = "host=localhost port=5433 dbname=prueba user=postgre password=josec123";
```

Por

```
$conex = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5433 dbname=prueba user=postgre password=josec123");
```

Ahora prueba, debería llenarte el **select**

Comment: graciaaas :D no me habia fijado de ese detalle :)